# Adding a number into a LinkedList, inside an ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist, linked-list, hashtable

I'm trying to add an integer into a LinkedList; however, I'm not sure how to add the integer to an already existing LinkedList.

```
class HashChaining extends HashTable {

private ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> chains;
private HashFunction function;

   HashChaining (Hashfunction function) {

      this.function = function;
      this.chains = new ArrayList<>(capacity);
        for (int i=0; i<capacity; i++)
            chains.add(i, new LinkedList<>());
   }

   void insert(int key) {
        int location = function.apply(key);
        chains.add(location, new LinkedList<Integer>(chains.get(location).push(key)));

   }
```

Comment: JDK `LinkedList` doesn't have `push` that would return the list. And it's not true that you aren't sure how to add elements to lists: you've already done that once in constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html), you'll see, that a method `add​(int index, E element)` inserts an elements at a given index. What you want to achieve is to add an element to an inner-list:

```
chains.get(location).add(key)
```

`chains.get(location)` will retrieve an inner `LinkedList` on a position given by `location`, then into this list, you can add your element.